Completely Replace AD Group Membership with One PowerShell Command
Is there a way using Set-ADGroup or a similar PowerShell command to completely replace the membership list of an AD group with a provided list?
I know this can be accomplished using loops with many add/remove commands and checking current members against the new complete list, but that seems like a poor solution when I already have the complete list that includes everybody that should now be a member of the group and could just swap out the old list for the new.
I did a lot of searching for this, but the only thing I could find that actually addressed what I am trying to do without just using loops with many updates was this other question: PowerShell Set-ADGroup replace member multiple domains (FSP)
First of all, does this method even truly work to update a group's members?  Second, in my case, I am only working with a single domain - will using each user's sAMAccountName or DN work in that case rather than having to construct a particular string containing each user's SID as the OP in that question did?  sAMAccountName would be ideal since I will have that already in the source data.
I am going to resort to some trial and error with a test group and see what I can figure out, but surely someone has done this before....  My use case is that we have AD groups we want to maintain via automation, and we are pulling the complete list of all people who should currently be members by querying our ERP database.
EDIT: I did some testing using Set-ADGroup -Replace @{ Member = $memberArray }, where $memberArray contained a few different things, and this is what I found so far:

$memberArray = array of sAMAccountName strings => does NOT work (throws an "internal error occurred" error)
$memberArray = array of ADUser objects obtained from Get-ADUser => does NOT work (throws some kind of type mismatch / conversion error, it seems the cmdlet is expecting a string array)
$memberArray = array of DN strings => DOES work, and I verified the new group membership using both Get-ADGroup and the AD Users and Computers GUI interface

So this confirms that it is possible, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if there's any way of formatting the strings in the input array such that AD will know what to do with a sAMAccountName?  Otherwise I will have to have the script obtain the DN for every user, and that's a lot of efficiency lost when I already have a unique identifier for each of them in their sAMAccountName.

Try a "test group." If there are problems, provide an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example) and any error messages as part of the question.

@lit See edit. TL;DR: got it to work with DNs, but would really like a way to use sAMAccountName if possible

If you have two lists with you then the following two lines may help

import-csv oldlist.csv | foreach { Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $oldmember -MemberOf "ADGroup"}

import-csv newlist.csv | foreach { Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $newmember -MemberOf "ADGroup"}



The AD Member property is an array of DNs (Distinguished Names), so you need to supply the membership that way.
For example (not sure what your upstream membership source is, but I'm sure you can work it into something like this), you can fetch the membership of an existing group via:
$membership = (Get-ADGroupMember ExistingGroup).DistinguishedName

Then you can set that to the new group's membership via:
Set-ADGroup NewGroup -Replace @{ Member = $membership }

Don't forget to wait for replication delay if you have multiple DCs and you're checking to see if the above actually worked.
